# Switch case confusion

Tags: switch-statement

I came across this problem and was confused when I got the answer wrong

```
 String s = "dog";
    switch( s )
    {
    case "dag" : System.out.print("7");
    case "dog" : System.out.print("8");
    case "dug" : System.out.print("9");
    }
```

The answer comes out to 89 but I'm not sure why. I thought it was just 8. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: As an aside, generally you want to define a default case at the bottom, even if it's just to exit the switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because you don't `break;` after you've found a match, so it will continue to fall through. It's done in such a way so you can catch multiple things at once:

```
case 1:
case 2:
case 3:
    // do something for 1-3
    break;
```

With your code, you'd need

```
switch (s) {
    case "dag":
        System.out.print("7");
        break;
    case "dog":
        System.out.print("8");
        break;
    case "dug":
        System.out.print("9");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use break.

```
case "dog": //print
            break;
```

Comment: You should explain what `break;` does.